# I want to list data as shown in output table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, listagg

HI guys i am using ORACLE 11G.
I have table like

```
dept    employee
10        a
10        b
10        c
10        d
20        p
20        q
20        r
20        s
```

And i want output like this

```
dept     employee
10         a
10         a,b
10         a,b,c
10         a,b,c,d
20         a,b,c,d,p
20         a,b,c,d,p,q
20         a,b,c,d,p,q,r
20         a,b,c,d,p,q,r,s
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And what exactly keeps you from doing this? What is it you want us to tell you?

Comment: I want sql query

Comment: This is not how stackoverflow works. You are supposed to show some effort and tell us where you got stuck. Do you know how to concatenate strings in SQL? Have you tried something with this technique? What has stopped you from writing the query yourself? What approaches to the problem have you thought of so far?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a self-join with `LISTAGG()` function like the one below

```
SELECT MAX(e2.dept) AS dept,
       LISTAGG(e2.employee,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e1.employee) AS employees
  FROM emp e1
  JOIN emp e2
    ON e1.employee >= e2.employee
 GROUP BY e1.employee
 ORDER BY dept, employees
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b238ca74e3e6625b60afd2356dbc99a6)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can simply use ListAgg as a windowing function:

```
Select dept, ListAgg(employee,',') Over (Order by dept, employee) as emp
From mytable
Order by dept, employee
```

There will be an extra comma in the ListAgg function but you can wrap it in a substr function to trim it off.

Comment: That is a good idea, but you got the syntax wrong and Oracle doesn't allow a windowing clause for `LISTAGG` which would be needed here. `listagg(employee, ',') within group (order by dept, employee) over (order by dept, employee rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as emp` fails with `ORA-30487: ORDER BY not allowed here`. And if we remove it, we get `ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification` :-(

Comment: Try it without the Within Group.  I'm doing this from memory on my phone, but I did this kind of query often in Oracle.  Just uncertain of how to partition the entire result set as one partition... 1. Omit it, 2. Partition By without a target or 3. Partition By Null (like PostgreSQL).

Comment: I'm not getting it to work. It would be great if you looked into this, when you have time. I would like to see, if this is possible, because this is the best approach to the task.

Comment: I went back to the SQL Reference and there is 'special' syntax for ListAgg.  For use as an analytic function, you do ListAgg(args) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY order list) OVER (PARTITION BY grouplist).  You need the OVER to signal it as an analytic function, not aggregate. I am still unsure of the syntax to partition as an entire set: OVER () or OVER (PARTITION BY).

Comment: It would just be `OVER ()`. However, as you don't want the whole employee list per row, but only the employees up to that row, you need a windowing clause as mentioned above and it seems this is not supported for `LISTAGG` yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
select e.*,
       (select listagg(e2.employee, ',') within group (order by e2.employee)
        from emp e2
        where e2.employee <= e.employee
       ) as employees
from emp e;
```

Notes:

1. I often find that correlated subqueries are faster than `join`/`group by`, because they avoid the outer aggregation.
2. This assumes that the ordering is by employee, but that is not clear.  It might also be by department.  That would require adjusting the correlation clause.
3. Oracle has a default limit of 2000 or 4000 characters for `listagg()` results.  If your table has any size or the names are long, you will exceed this threshold.

Comment: ListAgg limit is installation-dependent and depends on the data type you pass it.  From the reference manual:  "The maximum length of the return data type depends on the value of the
MAX_STRING_SIZE initialization parameter. If MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED, then
the maximum length is 32767 bytes for the VARCHAR2 and RAW data types. If
MAX_STRING_SIZE = STANDARD, then the maximum length is 4000 bytes for the
VARCHAR2 data type and 2000 bytes for the RAW data type."